# Tests slowing down while going through select combinations

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, automated-tests

I am using Python and Selenium to test my storefront's customization options, and noticed that the tests slow down significantly over time.

Specifically, I have a number of `<select>` tags on the page, each of which has a number of `<option>` tags as children. Each change in combination Ajax-queries a new price, which Selenium waits for via explicit waits for the loading animation to first appear and then disappear before changing to the next option.

As I have 5 different select fields with 3-10 options each, the whole test takes a while to run. However, there seems to be a huge discrepancy between earlier combinations and later ones – while the earlier ones typically load for less than a second, the very last ones can show the loading animation for up to 20 seconds before changing the price.

The issue doesn't appear to be with the machine the test is running on as both CPU and memory usage are moderate. I'm very curious what may be causing this degradation in performance over time – would be very grateful if anyone has an idea. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which browser or driver binary are you controlling with selenium?  If it takes less time to instance your driver binary than wait,  you may wish to consider writing the script to re-instance the driver binary each iteration.  Cookies and other data can be passed to the new instance of the driver binary.

Comment: I am using Chrome Webdriver as PhantomJS seemed to exacerbate the issue. Could you elaborate on what you mean with re-instance the driver? The relevant data from the instance would be the login session and the current state of the selects

Comment: Basically write the script to quit and create a new Chromedriver each combination. driver.quit() : driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver').

Answer (score 0):

Many selenium users have had their tests impacted by animations.  To test the changing prices alone, it may be best to disable animations.  Even if you intend on testing animations, sometimes the more complicated experiences/results with selenium are layered and removing variables one by one from testing will provide greater control and give you a chance to test each layer individually.

http://marcgg.com/blog/2015/01/05/css-animations-failing-capybara-specs/

Additionally, I have experienced some versions of driver binaries to become slow for mostly reasons that were localized to my test environment.  It may help you to use a design pattern that instances a new driver binary for each test and destroys the driver when the test is complete.  Doing so will add some additional overhead when executing your code; however, it is an estimable time and can be included in the expectations.